# (Anylogic) Task priority in Service blocks

Tags: anylogic

I use a variable of the agents to define the task priority of a service block. The value of this variable can change while the agent is in the queue. Will change the position of the agent in the queue? Or to define its position is it only consulted the value of the variable at the moment the agent arrives to the queue?
I include an example (A_i - agent number i; V_i - value of variable to agent i):

(Time = 1): A_1 (V_1 = 10), A_2 (V_2 = 8)
Queue_1: A_1, A_2

(Time = 2): A_1 (V_1 = 10), A_2 (V_2 = 12)
Queue_2? Does the queue change to: A_2, A_1? Or the system only consider the initial values of the variable and the queue remains: A_1, A_2?

Answer (score 0):

> Will change the position of the agent in the queue? Or to define its position is it only consulted the value of the variable at the moment the agent arrives to the queue?

Only on arrival. But you can easily test this yourself with a toy model (good practice anyway).

If you want to manage sorting yourself dynamically, consider using a `Wait` block instead and free agents from it based on your own (current) priorities